# Multiple actions were found that match the request C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to point to my action, basically I have 1 controller that has different methods, I want to point to the different methods, everything worked well when I had 1 method called create, now I have 1 called `createDocument` (ignore best practice REST from now). So every time I need to point to the `createDocument` it fails and I get this (Postman).

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nCreate on type server.Controllers.DocumentController\r\nCreateDocument on type server.Controllers.DocumentController",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

**I just have this in my controller:**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateDocument([FromBody]List<DocumentDetails> details)
{
    return Ok(200);
}
```

It doesn't enter the controller I tried to debug it, the other method that I have works well it enters without problem.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create([FromBody]AppDocument document)
        {
```

**my route configuration is like this:**

```
namespace server
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with the parameter I am receiving, I receive a jsonArray like this:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Table",
    "rows": 1,
    "cols": 1,
    "cells": 1
  },
  {
    "key": "Paragraph",
    "text": "asda",
    "fontSize": 14
  },
  {
    "key": "Paragraph",
    "text": "asda",
    "fontSize": 14
  },
  {
    "key": "Paragraph",
    "text": "asda",
    "fontSize": 14
  }
]
```

**and for that I created 2 models the first that has a simple list**

```
namespace server.Models
{
    public class DocumentDetails
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<DocumentAtributes> atributes { set; get; }
    }
}
```

**the second that has the possible props inside the list elements**

```
namespace server.Models
{
    public class DocumentAtributes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String key { get; set; }
        public String rows { get; set; }
        public String cols { get; set; }
        public String cells { get; set; }
        public String fontSize { get; set; }
        public String width { get; set; }
        public String height { get; set; }
        public String base64 { get; set; }
        public String align { get; set; }
        public String text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are showing the wrong routes. If this is web api then we need to see `WebApiConfig` which by default uses `api/{controller}/{id}` route template

Comment: You probably need to add `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` to your `WebApiConfig`, but it'd be better if we could see your `WebApiConfig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `WebApiConfig` route template to recognize action names in the route template as the default convention based route template is usually `api/{controller}/{id}`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

You should also update the actions with `[HttpPost]` attributes.

```
public class DocumentController : ApiController {

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateDocument([FromBody]List<DocumentDetails> details) {
        //...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create([FromBody]AppDocument document) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in your js code where you call the api. And i believe you should declare how a method should receive the request.

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateDocument([FromBody]List<DocumentDetails> details)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Adding HttpPost attribute makes the CreateDocument method only receive post requests.